# C# NativeMessaging to Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am trying to create a plugin/listener to have an external application pump messages into my SPA page/app.

I've created manifests, JS files, and added a reg entry, but to no avail, my listeners aren't getting triggered.

I've got:

// JavaScript source code

Native.js - Plugin

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(request);
      console.log(sender);
      console.log(sendResponse);
  });
```

Manifest.json - Plugin
    {
        "manifest_version": 2,

```
    "name": "Native Messaging Example",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "Native.js" ]
    },
     "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [ "*://localhost/*", "*://casetest/*", "*://case/*" ]
    }
}
```

---

C#

Program.js

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ChromeNativeMessaging
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenStandardStreamOut("data");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OpenStandardStreamOut(string stringData)
        {
            String str = "{\"text\": \"" + stringData + "\"}";
            //String str = stringData;
            Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();

            stdout.WriteByte((byte)str.Length);
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
            stdout.WriteByte((byte)'\0');
            Console.Write(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.json

```
    {
    "name": "com.example.nativeMessage",
    "description": "Hello World App",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\sas\\Documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\ChromeNativeMessaging\\ChromeNativeMessaging\\bin\\Debug\\ChromeNativeMessaging.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://gbdadncpjaecammkmeolpbembeedjohb/"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome never listens to native connections from outside (`onMessageExternal` does not apply), nor does running your C# code magically contact Chrome.

Only your JavaScript side can initiate the connection (by running a new copy of the Native Host), after which you can keep the connection open (if you do it with `connect()`).

So if you want to be notified of events that happen outside the browser, you need to start the native host from your extension side and then process those events in the native host.

All in all, you should (re-)read the documentation in its entirety: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: From reading around on the internet, I was thinking the posts must be missing something for C# to 'magically' connect. I'll re-read and re-think my solution - thanks!

Comment: Basically, you can't knock on Chrome's door directly. But you can make a small Native Host module that acts like a proxy/daemon, runs in the background and listens to whatever you want to listen to.